# Is it possible to generate a string-enum in typescript with random or same strings?

Tags: typescript, enums

TypeScript string-based enums are more strict than numeric enums. These traits are desirable in a very strict/typesafe environment. For example, you cannot really assign a string value to a field that is set to string-enum.

However, creating a string enum is a cumbersome activity:

```
const enum Actions {
    LOAD = "0", SUCC = "1", FAIL = "2"
}
```

In the above example, the `string` value of each enum fields is not really critical. It can be simply any random string.

Is there a way or a TS compiler option where an enum is by default string-based instead of number based? const or plain normal enum will work.

Comment: I assume your problem with numeric enums is the [support for bitwise operations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26362)?  Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to generate string enums automatically.  I'm guessing the answer to this question is just "no" unless someone else has a clever idea I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz, That is exactly what I needed. Too sad, it is still too much of a pain to create good Tagged Unions with minimum boilerplate.